# Is it possible to create multi scheme view in RedShift and how?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have multipale schemes in Redshift that are similar to one another 
basically for every new customer a new scheme is created.

in each scheme i have products table: product_id , product_name
and i have one view that present the scheme_name and scheme_id.

I need to create a single view that will show all the product_id and product_name with the scheme_id next to it.

so in the end i will have one view with all products from all schemes and the scheme id so i will know to which one it belongs.

how can i create a dynamic view for it?

Answer (score 0):

Within a database you specify a schema then a "." then the table.

e.g.

```
create view views.demo
as
select *
from schema1.table1 as a
join schema2.table2 as b on a.id=b.table1_id
```

you can create this dynamically OUTSIDE of redshift using python or similar

Comment: thx, maybe i missed it but what i need is to create it dynamically, so each new customer is new scheme that need to be added automatically with out me editing the script each time.

Comment: Like i said "you can create this dynamically OUTSIDE of redshift using python or similar". thats it - no other options.

Comment: yes i guess if i'm going to use python outside it will much more flexible, thx